# IDEA configuration for TDD

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, tdd

I have been using IDEA 13 for over a month now and now I'm trying to use it for TDD. What I find a bit frustrating is that before each test Make is run. What I would like to see is tests to start almost instantaneously like in Eclipse. I switched on auto-compile and removed Make from the JUnit run configuration, but now I'm facing the problem that the classes are not autocompiled fast enough and sometimes I get a green bar when I should get a red bar, and sometimes IDEA complains that it can't find the test class etc.

Is there any way I can fix these problems and enjoy TDD flow same way as in Eclipse?

Comment: I agree, it is something which deserves to [create an issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA). I just tried compiling of a project containing 1 small class, it always took 1,5s when the class was changed and 0,5 when not... That is bad.

Comment: I can't say I've noticed a problem, but then I'm using IDEA 15 on a fairly fast machine. Is there a reason you're using 13? It's possible there have been improvements in the last couple of versions.

Comment: @jyriand Please mark as answered

Comment: Can't mark it answered because it doesn't have any answers, and it doesn't let mark my own question as answer.